# Read existing XGboost ml model in spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, xgboost

I have trained XGboost ml model.
I need to use this in my spark application.

How to load this model in Spark using python or pyspark

Comment: were you able to resolve this?I have a similar problem where model is trained in python and i want to use spark for scaling up the prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XGBoost4J-Spark](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/xgboost4j_spark_tutorial.html) The project integrates XGBoost and Apache Spark by fitting XGBoost to Apache Spark’s MLLIB framework.